# Can not implicitly convert object to System.collections.generic.Dictionary error when reading a json file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am wiring a simple console application to migrate data from one system to a different one. To resume the migration if at an point it fails, i am reading the migrated file path and check if the file exists or not and read the contents of the file into a dictionary if exists. And also from the first system the file read as a json file, so i am also using jsonconvert in the if /else, But with my code its giving me the error - 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to SystemCollections.Generic.Dictionary. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ' in the second line of code.

```
static string MigratedPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "..", "..", "migrated.json");

static Dictionary<string, int> Migrated = File.Exists(MigratedPath) ? (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath))) : new Dictionary<string, int> ();
```

```
Sample JSON file content:
{ 
    "id" : "id_123"
    "createdBy" : "username", 
    "createdDate" : "2019-05-07", 
    "changedBy" : "username", 
    "changedDate" : "2019-05-07", 
    "type" : "type-1", 
    "name" : "xxxxxx",
    "description"  : "desc_xxxxxx",
    "priority"  :  "Major"
    "comments"  : "comments_11111"
},
{ 
     "id" : "id_456"
    "createdBy" : "username", 
    "createdDate" : "2019-05-07", 
    "changedBy" : "username", 
    "changedDate" : "2019-05-07", 
    "type" : "type-1", 
    "name" : "yyyyy",
    "description"  : "desc_yyyyy",
    "priority"  :  "Major"
    "comments"  : "comments_22222"
}, .......
```

The error is coming in the Dictionary declaration code line, I tried with giving (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath), 1) to be same format as the Dictionary(string, int). It didn't solve the issue. I am pretty new to C#, please provide any pointers on how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It **must** be runnable, as is, from a fresh new console app. And it **must** include the smallest possible JSON file to reproduce the issue. Even better if you can remove the `File.ReadAllText` from the sample, and instead just embed the JSON string **in the code** as a `string`.

Comment: Why do you try to assign a string to a variable of type `Dictionary<string, int>`? A string is not convertible (neither explicitly nor implicitly) to a dictionary, obviously. And your attempt to cast the string as `object` feels like you want to force the string to become a dictionary with sheer w̶i̶l̶l̶ magic power...

Comment: I tried first with  ~~~ static Dictionary<string, int> Migrated = File.Exists(MigratedPath) ? (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath))) : new Dictionary<string, int> ();  ~~~ But it gave the error Object can not be mapped and Dictionary expecting String,int values . So tried changing it to ~~~ static Dictionary<string, int> Migrated = File.Exists(MigratedPath) ? ((object)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath)).ToString(), 1) : new Dictionary<string, int> (); ~~~

Comment: Not sure why your write something like this if you can simplify it, specially if it is not working as is? When the file exists, what does this code return? Is it returning a valid pair to insert in a dictionary?JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath)

Comment: You can deserialize that JSON (when you have fixed it) to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. But I'ld sugget to deserialize to a `List<class>`.

Comment: If I can't copy and paste it into a console app and run it - it isn't yet a [mcve]. _Please remove the file based logic from your code - we don't need to see that. We need to see a string initialised with the JSON, and the code you are using to try and deserialise that string - nothing more, nothing less._

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

For the ternary operator(?:), the return type should be same in both the conditions. In your case `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` returns an `Object` and in else condition you are returning a new Dictionary object so there is type miss match for which you have to do explicit type casting or use generic `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>`

The 2nd issue is the JSON you are trying to convert is not in the dictionary format it is in a `List` format so you should create a class to represent this data and your code would look like

```
List<MyClass> Migrated = File.Exists(MigratedPath) ? (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(File.ReadAllText(MigratedPath))) : new List<MyClass>();
```